# jQuery - dynamically set filter method

Tags: jquery, variables, methods, parameters

I'm looking to combine some code but I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible.  Basically I have a function with a bunch of if/else statements, and there is one line that is similar throughout all the different cases:

```
$('#selector).prev('.class-selector').addClass('current');
$('#selector).next('.class-selector').addClass('current');
$('#selector).last('.class-selector').addClass('current');
$('#selector).first('.class-selector').addClass('current');
```

Are there any ways I can set the filter method (`prev`, `next`, `last`, `first`) as a variable so I don't have to repeat this line all over my function?  I tried passing a parameter to the function and using a variable as the method:

```
$('#selector).variable('.class-selector').addClass('current');
```

but that doesn't work. I get:

> object has no method 'variable'" error.

I vaguely understand why this doesn't work, based on how jQuery code is read. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not much shorter, but it's definitely more condensed :)

```
for (var i = 0, fns = ['prev', 'next', 'last', 'first'], fn; fn = fns[i]; ++i) {
    $('#selector')[fn]('.class-selector').addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is right along the lines of what I was looking for, and I was able to figure it out from here.  It was basically just the [fn] syntax I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $all = $('#selector .class-selector')
$all.eq(0).addClass('current'); //first
$all.eq(4).addClass('current'); //fifth
$all.eq($all.length-1).addClass('current'); //last
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it as a jquery plugin...

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.pnlf = function(class_selector, current) {
        this.prev(class_selector).addClass(current);
        this.next(class_selector).addClass(current);
        this.last(class_selector).addClass(current);
        this.first(class_selector).addClass(current);

        return this;
    };
})( jQuery );

// Use the plugin on the selected element...
$("#selector").pnlf("class-selector", "current");
```